# How to increase cloud shell quota?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

I have currently reached my cloud shell quota. From my understanding, the quota can only be reached if we keep open that many cloud shell instances at one time. Is there any way to kill those cloud shell instances and then set a new limit to start over?

Comment: Which quota? Each user gets one Cloud Shell instance. You are limited to 60 hours per week. Once you exceed that time, you must wait until the quota is refreshed. If you need more time than 60 hours, launch a Compute Engine VM.

Comment: I understand it now. I changed mine to 8. I think that's the problem. I need to create a vm!

Comment: Can we ssh and use gke cluster nodes as vm?

Answer (score 2):

Just like John Hanley mentioned, the [default weekly Cloud Shell quota](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quotas-limits#usage_quotas) is **60 hours** and if you need more, you could [launch a Compute Engine VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).

In addition, you can request to increase your quota by using the Google Cloud Console. You can follow this link on [requesting higher quota](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota).