# Is there a way to view the usage of cloudshell for previous weeks?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I am using Google Cloudshell as an IDE and noticed there is a weekly quota that counts the number of hours of usage for a given week. I want to keep a log of the number of hours that I was active on Google Cloudshell for a given week.
**Is there a way to view the cloud shell usage from previous weeks?**

Cloudshell Quota Screen:

[image: Google Cloudshell Quota Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quotas-limits#usage_limits), a quota limits the amount of a specific shared Google Cloud resource that your Cloud project is allowed to utilize. This includes network, computer, and software resources.

> Quotas are part of a system that does the following:
>
> - Monitor your use or consumption of Google Cloud products and services.
> - Restricts your consumption of those resources for reasons including ensuring fairness and reducing spikes in usage.
> - Maintains configurations that automatically enforce prescribed restrictions.
> - Provides a means to make or request changes to the quota.

In order to comply with the restrictions, the threshold or usage data was not publicly disclosed that is why it doesn't show logs of how many hours a week you were using Google Cloud Shell. Also, there is no option to view a Cloud Shell usage quota from previous weeks. And by default, it only displays usage quota for the current week.

In addition, once you've reached the limit, you have to wait until the given day and time for it to refresh. You can use the below workarounds to increase the quota limit:

- To request a quota increase, contact [Cloud Customer Care](https://cloud.google.com/support).
- The default weekly Cloud Shell quota is 50 hours and according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71903853/how-to-increase-cloud-shell-quota), if you need more time than 60 hours you can launch a Compute Engine VM. You can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) for more information.

However, this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_all_quota_console) might help if you want to view quota usage and limits for all resources in your project.